# Team doesn't take my code review comments seriously

Tags: code, quality, attitude

I am a mid level software developer in a small software company. 
I have been here for the last 8 months and due to my approach with code reviews **I was added to the mandatory reviewers list early on.**

I came here from a fairly large organization where the turnover rate was very low and every developer was extremely involved in the software development process. Coding standards were followed religiously and code quality was everything.

I came to this company to learn something different, being smaller company I thought I would learn more than I did back at my last job. Since, a few months, I have noticed a careless attitude among my team members when it comes to documentation, code quality and the approach towards code reviews is appalling. I being one of the reviewers on the code reviews, it is very obvious to me. I have to constantly remind them to follow the agreed upon code standards, to document stuff and just take ownership. I am not in a position to ask them to do it explicitly. Their attitude is starting to annoy me and almost stress me out. This attitude is same throughout all levels be it a junior developer or a more senior developer than me.

I cannot simply ignore the basic mistakes that are made in the reviews and let that code go in the production. One bad coder, but senior developer, came to me to ask me to back off on code reviews.

**I have already talked to my manager** (who is also their manager) about all this, but from his response it sounded to me like he has no control over them (he started a few weeks after me) so he is relatively new.

If you were in my situation, what would you do? Would you change your attitude to not care anymore?

Some e.g. of issues that I see in the code reviews:

1. Newly created unused methods/variables that are left as it is.
2. Naming conventions for new classes, properties, methods not followed. Properties for instance are left all lower case.
3. Obvious bugs are ignored and they get into arguments like the the back off comment.

Comment: "I am not in a position to ask them to do it explicitly" but isn't that what a code reviewer is?

Comment: @Kate Gregory  -  Yes, kind of but not in a way that says, he look you either do it right or I'll put you on a PIP

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @aaaaa says reinstate Monica  - I want to achieve consistency in the code and avoid stupid bugs in production.

Comment: @user163824 That's not really a /workplace goal. It seems that you were given a code review job, but you are not owner of the code reviewed, nor your views are not really respected by the other devs. Did you ever take the time to explain in the PR why something could, and should, be done better, maybe even writing bits yourself just to demonstrate the importance?

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica dunno, if OP struggles to promote writing better code via code reviews then whatever is going on is going to be at least partially OPs fault. Stuff is never black and white.

Comment: Are seniors pushing back if you comment on  "basic mistakes" or are they pushing back on parts of the coding guidelines they do not disagree on? 
If the latter this seems to be at least two different problems

Comment: Would there be at least one example of these mistakes you could provide?

Comment: @user163824 what impact does code review do to the whole development process? Can the commit/code submitted for your review be rejected/sent for rework as a result of the code review?

Comment: @Kate: No. The reviewer cannot _order_ the developer to make a change. The question is “is the change an agreed improvement that is worth the additional work”.

Comment: @AlexanderM Usually the reviewer’s job is to merge the change, and if he doesn’t do it, it doesn’t get merged. If the developer agrees, fine. If the developer disagrees strongly then their manager has a problem.

Comment: OP, what is your manager attitude against the problem? Does he agree with you in the sense that more attention should be taken towards code quality? Can he bring this upper in the chain?

Comment: A partial fix for this, that would address point 2 and maybe 1, would be to add a checkstyle / linter step in your build process. That way, if this step fails, your pipeline can't build and the the PR is automatically denied. This would require reviewing your CI/CD processes and discussing with your colleagues how strict the linter / checkstyle should be.

Comment: @gnasher729 If this is the case then I do not see the problem here. If you feel the code is not up to your standards you write a review pointing out every single item you believe is wrong and do not merge until the issues are corrected. If people start to push on you you can simply explain that you cannot approve such code since it goes against your professional standards and defeats the purpose of the review (btw this is what I did in similar situation). Of course it wouldn't improve people overnight but slowly and surely you would either get there.

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/149100/56138

Answer (score 22):

> Their attitude is starting to annoy me and almost stress me out. This
>   attitude is same throughout all levels be it a junior developer or a
>   more senior developer than me.
>
> I don't know if it is the culture or me being a female in a male
>   dominated team that is causing the friction.

To me this appears to be a culture mismatch.

You came from a large company where folks generally followed the rules. You are now in a smaller, more free-wheeling company. And it's bothering you.

> I have already talked to my manager (who is also their manager) about
>   all this, but from his response it sounded to me like he has no
>   control over them (he started a few weeks after me) so he is
>   relatively new.
>
> If you were in my situation, what would you do?

First I would probably ask to be removed from the code review team since that seems to be at the core of your stress.

Then I would either learn to accept the culture as it is while still doing excellent work, or find a new company (perhaps a larger, stricter company that follows more formal rules), and leave this one.

> Would you change your attitude to not care anymore?

Absolutely not.

I always cared. If the culture around me was such that to get along, I would have to stop caring, I left.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Running away from the code reviews and looking for a new job is surely going to ease OP's stress, but it is not going to benefit the company, and as such should only be the last resort. There is nothing in the question that gives info on how much focus on quality there is in the upper management, which could make a difference in having the company willing to align with OP's culture or OP that has to align with the company's one ,or go away.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head so to speak. Do not fight battles you cannot win, that was one of the most important lessons for me in work (and life). It does not mean you give up on your standards. Just on the daunting task of convincing others. If you really cannot live with the environment it's healthier to leave. BTW Whoever made you, as new hire, mandatory reviewer is a total sadist.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the question, as it reads now:

> 1. I want to achieve consistency in the code and avoid stupid bugs in production
> 2. Part of my job is code reviewer
> 3. I have to constantly remind them to follow the agreed upon code standards
> 4. I cannot simply ignore the basic mistakes
> 5. My manager has no control over team

Ask your manager what is your job exactly. Is it "code quality advocate" or "code reviewer"? It is probably latter, so drop the (3) behavior.

What is the process of code review? Is it `commit->review->comment/accept`? Then do just that. Refer all grief from the team to your manager. They have appointed you to do an important task, you seem to have appropriate background. **Their job is to help you do these tasks.**

There is a chance you are doing not a very good job, for example, hanging on indentation, naming conventions, or something else inappropriate for current state of project or product. But that is the problem for your manager to explain to you. If there are written documents, try to link them in your comments, and go together with manager through the guidelines to figure out **how you can do your job better**.

Comment: I think you have misread a bit, the OP is an engineer at the company who was also added to the reviewer list. But nowhere does she state that this is her primary job, or even focus. It's fairly normal for most if not all devs to be part of the reviewing process for at leat their projects.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul yeah, i wanted to focus on the fact that OP has a specific task she got problem with. "job"~"task" here. edited for clarity, thanks

Answer (score 3):

A technical code-reviewer gains authority by, essentially, being wise, right, and capable of explaining why he's wise and right.  Not by management fiat.

So you're going to have to win hearts and minds.

As a senior code-reviewing guy, I have strong opinions on right and wrong when it comes to code.  ("Hell is other people's code", to misquote Sartre).

NEVERTHELESS:

I take great care to distinguish "you must fix this because the code does not work" from "I would prefer a different style" (each of which comes in various degrees of insistence).  Focus on what's broken. Over time people voluntarily take up my preferences - because they're good, not because I say so (I'm not omniscient, I've just experienced sufficient crap to have suggestions on how to avoid it).

"Do this because it's the coding standard" is never going to convince anyone.  Consistency is a good thing, but nevertheless the rationale for the particular convention is needed. Otherwise consistency is just continuing to do things wrong because you've always done them wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot simply ignore the basic mistakes that are made in the reviews
>   and let that code go in the production.

Then don't. If you found a defect, write it down as a ticket and don't accept the code until it was fixed. I wrote articles under defects until it was fixed.

> I am not in a position to ask them to do it explicitly

Then you are not doing a code review.

If you are not their manager, nobody will listen to you - it'a a basic human behavior which most people even proud of. Especially in small companies. As you stated, they even ignore your (male) manager. No need to be stressed about it.

---

However, if I am missing some details and you are certain you've been discriminated by your gender, then they have no right to stress you out due to your gender, and here is the pattern you should follow:

1. Create a ticket or documentation for the defect you found, and document it was ignored by others.
2. Then document a defect which was found by a male developer, and notice it was fixed as requested. (If there are several reviewers as you said, it is better - collect the tickets which are solved and ignored.)
3. Face with your manager with the print out those 2 evidence, and ask for the reason why your defect were ignored and you were behaved differently.

Gender discrimination is a serious issue which should not be treated lightly. You said you are "stressed", which means something is wrong - and don't hesitate to escalate the issue until you are completely satisfied.

Comment: Taking a pretty wild jump from admitting that they also ignore the male person on the team, but yet, somehow, you've made the stretch to suspect that there is gender discrimination at play, and not just issue with OP herself.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I made an edit to make it more clear - my intension was in case OP did not mention some details and she is certain about discrimination.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your manager what is expected of you in code-reviews (possibly with some anonymised examples from your reviews), get it in documented publicly and specifically, and follow that as best you can. If they continue to not follow these standards, it will be up to your manager to enforce the rules, not your problem.

If your standards are higher than those of your manager, then you'll have to relax your standards. It's a shame, but importantly, the issue is taken out of your hands. Unclear expectations are causing you undue stress at work, you should put pressure on your manager to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the focus on what your authority is and how you get people to comply is mistaken.

The purpose of code review is to catch bugs and improve code quality, not to produce perfect code. Insisting that code is perfect before you sign off on code review is the number one way to foster bad feelings and create a stalemate, where you don't sign off on code and the developers refuse to listen to you.

Above all, code review is a collaborative, team process. It needs to be done in a way that fosters team development and relationships, or at a minimum does no harm. Otherwise you'll end up with a team that hates each other and then no software will be developed, good code or not. Thus, when you code review the first thing you always have to do is Remember The Human:

**Bring code up a letter grade or two, not from an F to an A**

People who produce F-quality code aren't doing it on purpose. Either they're inexperienced or they just don't know better. You can't take a junior developer (or a senior developer with a lifetime of bad habits) and expect them to change all their habits in a day. Moreover, it's an unreasonable standard as no code is ever really perfect: even you make mistakes and miss things. Focus on two or three major deficiencies and address those in your code review, so that the code goes from a F to a C. Trust that over time your developers will get better and once they're producing C level code then you can worry about going to a B or an A.

**Tie feedback to principles, not opinions**

People have different opinions on how to build code- that's fine. If you insist that things are changed just because you would have done things differently then your feedback comes off as arbitrary and meaningless. Instead, tie feedback to specific principles: "this isn't scalable", "this isn't modular", "too much is happening in this one class or function", "the style guide says to do it this way."

**Frame feedback as requests, not commands**

You wouldn't tell your coworker to go get you a coffee. Use inclusive language, "We should add some error checking here."

**Split large reviews into small reviews**

Encourage your developers to submit small changesets and review them quickly. If you get 500 or 1000 lines of code and you come back a week later with five pages of changes to make it's incredibly demoralizing. If your developers know that small changes will be approved that afternoon or the next day then you will get small changesets and your feedback will automatically be small and manageable.

**Don't hold up approval over trivial changes**

Your co-workers are professionals. Trust their professionalism. If you only have a few comments say "X, Y, and Z are minor changes that would improve things, but I'm approving this change for now."

**Offer sincere praise where possible**

But only if it is truly sincere. You don't want to be the person who only has bad things to say. That person is just looking for reasons to shoot other people down. You want to be a mentor.

Comment: I disagree on exactly one point: "Use inclusive language" . This basically gives the reviewed code a chance to be pushed off. "Sure, someone at some point with more free time than I have right now can work on this tech debt"

Comment: @AthomSfere Ultimately the decision to do it now versus do it later depends on whether the code reviewer accepts or requires revision. If your code reviewers don't have authority to reject changes, then *anything* can be pushed off.

Comment: And while I agree, **Don't hold up approval over trivial changes** means you can't be unclear about who needs to make the changes and when. *This loop is potentially non-terminating. Please update the code so that I can approve the PR" is much, much better than "Someone needs to fix this potentially non-terminating loop". The 1st scenario says 1) Who must make the change and 2) What it means a specific task isn't complete. Of course, as I have done in the past: Open tech debt stories if it needs to be done by someone eventually.

Answer (score 0):

**You are trying to change an embedded way of doing things which probably arose due to the incentive structure of the company**

My company technically has coding standards, code review, documentation plans, etc. Whether anyone follows them depends on how close we are to the end of the sprint. Up to the end of the first 5 days, there will be unit tests, code review, and SQLs will be organized in their tickets. The remaining sprint time, things get iffy. Bugs in the frontend are generally of greater concern than bugs in the backend.

Why is that? The decision-makers are non-technical and generally prioritize what the customer sees and the features get out the door. We also have external clients we need to satisfy.  I haven't had a formal performance review yet, but the corporate goal with regard to software seems to be very much about getting features to production. We have all manner of older software that requires constant software developer support, so this has been the attitude for a long time.

The challenge is that things like code review and testing are not institutional goals but rather just team goals and the institution takes precedence.

Whether management realizes it or not at your company, they are probably the ones encouraging that behavior through what they reward,  what they complain about, and what they prioritize.

There is very little you can do about it as you are essentially going against management here.

Answer (score -2):

I very much like Joe's answer, but I'll expand on a few very alarming signs to me.

> I have to constantly remind them to follow the agreed upon code
>   standards, to document stuff and just take ownership.

When devs ignore coding standards it's rarely because they mischievously want to be sinister, almost always it's because the coding standards are unfit for purpose. What did you do towards resolving, or at least trying to figure out the core of the problem, besides constantly reminding people to follow them?

> I am not in a position to ask them to do it explicitly and hence they
>   seem to think I am the mom that they can just ignore when she yells.

Code reviews in teams are not seminars where one person tells another how to do things. It's a collaboration towards achieving better quality by having an open discussion among people working on the project. If you are acting like a nagging mom, rather than taking the time to explain and seek consensus with the other developers, why would you be surprised that they will simply start to ignore your feedback?

As you point out yourself, you are not their boss, you are just another developer, so act that way and if you want to convince someone to do something your way, use logic, charm and reason, rather than the stick which you were never given.

> I cannot simply ignore the basic mistakes that are made in the reviews
>   and let that code go in the production. One bad coder, but senior
>   developer, came to me to ask me to back off on code reviews.

That's a sign that you are at least partially the problem. Do not ignore it when someone senior on the team takes the time to give you brunt feedback like that. There clearly is something wrong with the way you are coming across, at least in context of this very team.

> I don't know if it is the culture or me being a female in a male
>   dominated team that is causing the friction.

I don't know where do you even got this idea from. Just because you are a female, doesn't mean that's why less than perfect interactions keep happening to you.

Answer (score -5):

Code quality doesn't matter. Sales do. Making a new product does, because it boosts sales. Re-write the code a hundred times, and your sales won't go up.

---

With that idea celebrated in the back of your mind, you have to also know that code quality does have value. It can allow new products to be built faster, and bugs to be resolved sooner. So *some* code quality is useful.

I argue that the amount of code quality should be such that the time spent on code quality was *slightly* less than the time saved when adding new features (due to the improved code quality).

---

In a small company, you need to be a little thoughtful about if your code quality arguments are hurting growth. A small but bad codebase can have things added to it pretty quickly, until it hits some point that it is no longer small and things are no longer added quickly. It's at this point that code quality matters - because code quality has a definite result (less time adding new things).

But until that time, while the codebase is relatively small, code quality adds only marginal value. So, to make your argument about code quality, you might want to consider what business objectives/bugs are the most pressing now and in the next year, and make an argument for particular code quality (reuse, naming, clarity, whatever) in those areas. You can then present this to your manager - "hey, the xyz component is seen as the big thing for our product, we should be proactive now to keep it cleanish so it doesn't cause problems later".

You won't be able to outright create code-quality everywhere, but as the *idea* sinks in, it will be easier to maintain.

---

There will always be sloppy code, (and that's why full integration tests are so useful - because you can clean it up), but it can generally be cleaned up. Code quality arguments should exist in the context of increased sales, otherwise they are purely theoretical.

Comment: "Code quality doesn't matter. Sales do. Making a new product does, because it boosts sales."

You are being downvoted because we are mostly developers, but this is genuinely how management generally looks at this stuff.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser yeh, i know, I'm a dev too - and until i started running my own company I didn't really have the same mindset. At the end of the say, you cannot make payroll without making sales, sales is *important* because developers really don't like working for free.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser They're getting downvoted because they start out with a bad absolute statement. The developer's job to convince management that technical debt is a real thing with consequences. There are lots of stories of software companies that get a year or two in and suddenly hit a wall when their dev team goes from 10 to 50 or their userbase explodes overnight. If bharal just stared with the second point (be mindful of where and why you spend time doing code maintenence, especially as a small company) nobody would downvote.

Comment: I'm a dev too, and I've come to realize the truth of this statement, so I upvoted.